# GAE/J: unable to register a custom ELResolver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, el

I need to register a custom `ELResolver` for a Google App Engine project.

Since it must be registered before any request is received, [as specified by the Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext.html#addELResolver(javax.el.ELResolver)):

> It is illegal to register an ELResolver after the application has 
>   received any request from the client. If an attempt is made to register 
>   an ELResolver after that time, an IllegalStateException is thrown.

I'm using a ServletContextListener:

```
public class RegisterCustomELResolver implements ServletContextListener { 

    @Override 
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) { 
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext(); 
        JspApplicationContext jspContext = 
            JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getJspApplicationContext(context); 
        jspContext.addELResolver(new MyELResolver()); 
    } 

    ... 
}
```

The problem is that `JspFactory.getDefaultFactory()` returns always null. I've alreay filled a bug report. Any idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure which servletcontainer GAE uses "under the hoods" (Jetty? Tomcat?), but this is recognizeable as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=39804) in Tomcat 6.x. A workaround is to force the loading of `JspRuntimeContext` yourself before getting the factory:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext");
```

See if this or similar hack helps.

Comment: good! Now I'm getting a `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;` exception. The JSP version is 2.0 wherese `getApplicationContext()` is defined for JSP 2.1. I'm definitively out of luck

Comment: `ELResolver` is JSP 2.1 as well. Is GAE really JSP 2.0? I'd expect it to be JSP 2.1. Is your `web.xml` declared as Servlet 2.5? Example here: http://snipplr.com/view/3775/minimal-webxml-webapp-descriptor-version-25/

Comment: I googled a bit and it seems that GAE comes with Servlet 2.5/JSP 2.1 API, but with Servlet2.4/JSP 2.0 impl. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1506 Weird :) Hope they get it fixed soon.

Comment: GAE is really JSP 2.0: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1506

Comment: Yes, JSP 2.0 impl.. I said that and I even posted the same link :)